# How do I visit localhost:9000 in cloud9 for Harp server ( Custom workspace )?

Tags: node.js, localhost, cloud9-ide, cloud9, harp

I am trying run a harp server using `harp server my-blog`, it is served at localhost:9000. How do I visit that in Cloud9 ?

I have tried all possible solutions available on the web like

`http://workspace-user.c9users.io:9000`
`http://workspace.user.c9users.io:9000`

and even the 7-digit one using mysql-cli nothing worked well !

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its working now, run harp this way, 
`harp server [path] --port 8080`

and in the browser go to
`http://workspace-username.c9users.io`